# How do I show specific swagger section base on condition from my .env?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a total of 50 sections of my Swagger. 
I only need to show 2 sections, base on a specific client.

Let's say. I have a flag in my `.env`

```
SWAGGER_CLIENT=xfinity
```

If `SWAGGER_CLIENT=xfinity`, I want to show 2 sections only.

1. Authentication
2. Comcast (specific section)

**How do I show specific swagger section base on the condition from my .env ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, I only want to show 2 sections to specific client name `xfinity`

I did this, and work perfectly

```
if (process.env.SWAGGER_CLIENT === 'xfinity') {
    tagFiles = tagFiles.filter(tagFile => ['anySection.json', 'Login.json'].includes(tagFile));
}
```

[image]